# Optimizing numpy concatenate operations for very large data sets

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, out-of-memory, large-data

I have a dictionary, with a very large number of keys (**~300k** and growing) and as values it has sets which also have a large number of items (**~20k**).

```
dictionary = {
    1: {1, 2, 3},
    2: {3, 4},
    3: {5, 6},
    4: {1, 5, 12, 13},
    5: set()
}
```

What I want to achieve is create two arrays:

```
keys  = [1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 4  4]
items = [1 2 3 3 4 5 6 1 5 12 13]
```

Which basically represent a mapping of each item in each set along with its corresponding key.

I tried using *numpy* for this job, but it still takes a very long time and I want to know if it can be optimized.

numpy code:

```
keys = np.concatenate(list(map(lambda x: np.repeat(x[0], len(x[1])), dictionary.items())))
items = np.concatenate(list(map(lambda x: list(x), dictionary.values())))

keys = np.array(keys, dtype=np.uint32)
items = np.array(items, dtype=np.uint16)

return keys, items
```

The second part is an attempt to try to reduce the memory footprint of those variables to account for their respective data types. But I know they will still default to 64bit variables in the first two operations (before applying the dtype change), so the memory will get allocated and I might run out of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to use `np.fromiter` here. It is certainly easier on the memory as it avoids creating all those temporaries.

Timings:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as it
from simple_benchmark import BenchmarkBuilder

B = BenchmarkBuilder()

@B.add_function()
def pp(a):
    szs = np.fromiter(map(len,a.values()),int,len(a))
    ks = np.fromiter(a.keys(),np.uint32,len(a)).repeat(szs)
    vls = np.fromiter(it.chain.from_iterable(a.values()),np.uint16,ks.size)
    return ks,vls

@B.add_function()
def OP(a):
    keys = np.concatenate(list(map(lambda x: np.repeat(x[0], len(x[1])), a.items())))
    items = np.concatenate(list(map(list, a.values())))
    return keys, items

@B.add_function()
def DevKhadka(a):
    keys = np.array(list(a.keys()), dtype=np.uint32).repeat([len(s) for s in a.values()])
    values = np.concatenate([np.array(list(s), np.uint16) for s in a.values()])
    return keys,values

@B.add_function()
def hpaulj(a):
    ks = list(it.chain.from_iterable([[item[0]]*len(item[1]) for item in a.items()]))                                           
    vls = list(it.chain.from_iterable(a.values()))
    return ks,vls


@B.add_arguments('total no items')
def argument_provider():
    for exp in range(1,12):
        sz = 2**exp
        a = {j:set(np.random.randint(1,2**16,np.random.randint(1,sz)).tolist())
     for j in range(1,10*sz)}
        yield sum(map(len,a.values())),a

r = B.run()
r.plot()

import pylab
pylab.savefig('dct2np.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

For this small sample, a pure list version is considerably faster than the numpy one:

```
In [14]: timeit list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[item[0]]*len(item[1]) for item in dictionary.items()]))                                           
2.71 µs ± 18.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [15]: timeit np.concatenate(list(map(lambda x: np.repeat(x[0], len(x[1])), dictionary.items())))                                                    
52.2 µs ± 284 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

and

```
In [24]: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(dictionary.values()))               
Out[24]: [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 13, 12, 5]
In [25]: timeit list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(dictionary.values()))        
876 ns ± 10.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [26]: timeit np.concatenate(list(map(lambda x: list(x), dictionary.values())))                                                                      
13.8 µs ± 32.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

And Paul Panzer's version:

```
In [41]: timeit np.fromiter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(dictionary.values()),'int32')                                                                
3.69 µs ± 9.07 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it will perform much better but straight forward way to do it is like this

```py
import numpy as np

keys = np.array(list(dictionary.keys()), dtype=np.uint32).repeat([len(s) for s in dictionary.values()])

values = np.concatenate([np.array(list(s), np.uint16) for s in dictionary.values()])

display(keys)
display(values)
```